JSON format for string
Getting string data from ajax request : result is dates and number of events on specific dates.
[['2012-06-20',13],['2012-06-21',2],['2012-06-22',2],['2012-06-24',1],['2012-07-04',1],['2012-07-05',4],['2012-07-13',1],['2012-08-14',1],['2012-08-15',1],['2012-08-17',1],['2012-08-20',1],['2012-08-26',1],['2012-08-30',4],['2012-09-01',8],['2012-09-04',13],['2012-09-08',1],['2012-09-09',2],['2012-10-06',1],['2012-10-08',7],['2012-10-09',18],['2012-10-14',12],['2012-10-15',3],['2012-10-17',2],['2012-10-18',5],['2012-10-20',4],['2012-10-24',1],['2012-10-31',9],['2012-11-02',3],['2012-12-05',1],['2012-12-20',3],['2012-12-23',1],['2012-12-25',3],['2012-12-29',1],['2013-01-02',3],['2013-01-03',2],['2013-01-04',3],['2013-01-10',6],['2013-01-11',2],['2013-01-18',1],['2013-02-20',5],['2013-02-26',2],['2013-03-08',1],['2013-03-12',2],['2013-03-23',1],['2013-04-01',1],['2013-04-03',4],['2013-04-04',1],['2013-05-02',1],['2013-05-25',6],['2013-05-28',1],['2013-05-29',1],['2013-05-30',1],['2013-06-04',1],['2013-06-10',1],['2013-06-17',1],['2013-08-31',3],['2013-09-08',1],['2013-09-30',2],['2017-05-07',2],['2017-05-19',1],['2017-05-21',1],['2017-05-22',1],['2017-05-29',1],['2017-05-31',3],['2017-06-08',1],['2017-06-13',1],['2017-06-15',1],['2017-06-23',1],['2017-06-28',1],['2017-07-30',1],['2017-08-17',3],['2017-08-22',1],['2017-08-23',1],['2017-08-24',2],['2017-08-31',1],['2017-09-04',1],['2017-09-05',1],['2017-09-08',1],['2017-09-17',8],['2017-09-26',1],['2017-10-02',2],['2017-10-03',1],['2017-10-04',3],['2017-10-31',2],['2017-11-07',1],['2017-11-08',1],['2017-11-14',2],['2017-11-20',2],['2017-12-06',1],['2017-12-15',1],['2018-01-02',1],['2018-01-09',2],['2018-01-11',3],['2018-01-15',2],['2018-01-17',2],['2018-03-14',2],['2018-03-27',2],['2018-04-11',2],['2018-04-19',1],['2018-04-23',2],['2018-05-29',1],['2018-06-04',1],['2018-08-07',1],['2018-10-31',2],['2018-11-01',2],['2018-12-05',1],['2018-12-06',1],['2018-12-09',3],['2019-03-03',1],['2019-03-07',4],['2019-03-09',3],['2019-03-10',8],['2019-03-18',1],['2019-04-15',13],['2019-10-14',1],['2019-12-11',1],['2020-01-08',3],['2020-01-14',1],['2020-01-20',6],['2020-01-28',1],['2020-02-16',2],['2020-02-25',1],['2020-04-15',1],['2020-05-11',1],['2020-05-18',1],['2020-05-23',2],['2020-05-27',4],['2020-05-28',1],['2020-09-03',17],['2020-09-22',1],['2020-09-29',1],['2020-10-01',2],['2020-10-02',2],['2020-10-07',3],['2020-12-01',1],['2021-02-10',1],['2021-02-22',2],['2021-11-29',3],['2021-11-30',2],['2022-04-09',1],['2022-04-26',3],['2024-03-31',1],['2024-04-20',3]]

Yes, this code brings an error "Uncaught SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 3 of the JSON data"
Code:
$.ajax({
  async: false,
  url: url,
  dataType: "text",
  success: function(data) {
            P1Tickets = JSON.parse(data);
        var plot1 = $.jqplot('ticket_weekly_p1_stati', [P1Tickets], {
            axes:{
                xaxis:{
                    renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer
                }
            },
            series:[{lineWidth:4, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
        });
        }
});

Anyone able to bring me clarity?
Br
Lars

That isn't JSON format. JSON uses double quotes around strings, not single quotes.

You need to fix the controller to send proper JSON.

That array of date+number is also suspect. Shouldn't that be an object with date and amount properties?

I was indeed returning wrong JSON format.
I was imploding and array with "," - that is why JSON.parse was unable to adhere ;-)
